# Song 3 by Mr Physicson

Tags: wordplay, music

Mr Physicson has been programming some nuclear reactor results filtering program. So, when he returned home tonight, he incorporated a bit of this new knowledge when he was singing to his son:

```
x=person:property(("small sized"&&"black skin")|("small sized"&&"red skin")|"good deeds")
set x_count=10

x_count x gathered on the evening to socially sustain themselves
A blockage of the upper airway resulted in x_count--

x_count x gave prolonged continuance to the aforementioned gathering
The consequent rest needed was overwhelming in one case so x_count--

x_count x went on an excursion to southwest United Kingdom
The scenary seduced a traveller, causing no return, so x_count--

x_count x were splitting wooden cylinders with raw tools
One had its target replaced with themselves, so x_count--

x_count x were messing with an Anthophila colony
One of its members reacted defensively, and thus x_count--

(one verse reducted, because the OP cannot figure its meaning with certainty)

x_count x went on an excursion to a large water body
The deceptive fish grabbed one so x_count--

x_count x went on an excursion to the show of various fauna
An Ursidae grabbed one so x_count--

x_count x were enjoying the topic star's gaze
One overdid it so x_count--

Since x_count==1, the last x was alone
It suicided by asphyxiation so x_count--
```

At this point, the young kid was fast asleep. Mr Physicson smiled. He then recalled the associated, marvellous mystery novel he read back then.

**What was he singing? What did he recall?**

Comment: Why `x_count--`, not `--x_count`? The postfix decrement operator returns *old* value, not *new* one (as was intended, I believe).

Comment: Heh, nice observation! I'll leave it as it is to not invalidate the answer, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mr Physicson is reciting:

> The poem known colloquially as "*[Ten Little Indians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Little_Indians)*", specifically this version:
>
>  ***Ten*** little Indian boys went out to dine;
>  *One choked his little self and then there were nine.*
>  ***Nine*** little Indian boys sat up very late;
>  *One overslept himself and then there were eight.*
>  ***Eight*** little Indian boys travelling in Devon;
>  *One said he'd stay there and then there were seven.*
>  ***Seven*** little Indian boys chopping up sticks;
>  *One chopped himself in halves and then there were six.*
>  ***Six*** little Indian boys playing with a hive;
>  *A bumblebee stung one of them and then there were five.*
>  ***Five*** little Indian boys going in for law;
>  *One got in Chancery and then there were four.*
>  ***Four*** little Indian boys going out to sea;
>  *A red herring swallowed one and then there were three.*
>  ***Three*** little Indian boys walking in the zoo;
>  *A big bear hugged one and then there were two.*
>  ***Two*** little Indian boys sitting in the sun;
>  *One got all frizzled up and then there was one.*
>  ***One*** little Indian boy left all alone;
>  *He went and hanged himself and then there were none.*
>
>  The words of each verse have been replaced with 'scienced up' synonyms, and at the end of each verse the number of boys ('*x*', which begins as 10) reduces by one, hence the programmers' commands "*set x_count=10*" at the beginning, and "*x_count--*" at the end of each verse.

This poem specifically reminds Mr Physicson of:

> The mystery novel *And Then There Were None* (1939) by Agatha Christie. In fact, the specific version of the rhyme quoted above was used in the 1945 film version based on the book.
>
>  The rhyme has its origins in minstrel songs and has been reworded many times over the years (hence the alternate versions suggested in line 1 of his 'code', referring to *("small sized"&&"black skin")|("small sized"&&"red skin")|"good deeds"*) to consider society's changing attitudes to race.

<sup>PS As for the redacted verse:</sup>

> <sup>'Chancery' is a branch of the court system in England and Wales - the line "*One got in Chancery and then there were four*" suggests that one of the protagonists has qualified for a career in law and has left the group. Furthermore, as @shoover points out in comments, this phrase has a double meaning, as being 'in Chancery' - as well as being a legal phrase - also [describes](https://www-collinsdictionary-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/in-chancery?amp_js_v=a3&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQIKAGwASDIAQE%3D#aoh=15886190538546&amp_ct=1588619090051&csi=1&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.collinsdictionary.com%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Fin-chancery) an 'awkward or embarrassing situation' (e.g. a scandal), which would be a more fitting interpretation for a rhyme where bad things befall the 10 protagonists...</sup>

Comment: A bit of trivia: the AC thing that the poem reminds Mr Physicson of was previously called rot13(Gra Yvggyr Vaqvnaf) and originally was rot13(fbzrguvat gung vf pbafvqrerq rkgerzryl bssrafvir gbqnl)

Comment: @shoover Indeed it was - however, I deliberately didn't delve into its origins so as to avoid any deep controversy or offence! The title I quote is already considered inappropriate by many - I definitely couldn't (and wouldn't want to) quote what it was called before that...

Comment: Yep, you already alluded to it anyway.

Comment: Since rot13(fbzrguvat onq unccrarq gb nyy bs gur yvggyr barf), perhaps a better interpretation for the redacted verse might be found in the idiom section at https://bit.ly/2WpNEVh

Comment: @shoover That might be worth a mention actually - thanks for pointing it out. Will edit...